# JupyterLab Desktop installation Windows error

Tags: jupyterlab

I attempted to install Jupyterlab Desktop version from [the exe file given in the following location](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-desktop/releases/latest/download/JupyterLab-Setup-Windows.exe). Windows and Norton throw errors saying threat detected. The file is not signed digitally and cannot be trusted. Is this normal?

[image]

Comment: So you can submit the sample to Microsoft and Norton and eventually the potential false positive will be handled.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your installation file on
[Virus Total](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload)
and it comes up as clean. This seems like a false positive by
Norton (which in my opinion isn't one of the best
antiviruses). You should only take the virus warnings
seriously if Defender is also warning about this
installation.

To be absolutely safe,
the official release download location for today is
[Jupyterlab Desktop v4.0.11-1](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-desktop/releases/tag/v4.0.11-1).

You could download again, uninstall what you have
installed using an  uninstaller like
[Revo Uninstaller Free](https://www.revouninstaller.com/products/revo-uninstaller-free/)
and do deep antivirus scans using Defender
and at least also
[Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/).

If after installing the new downloaded version
you still get messages about suspicious activities,
see the post
[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: I am confused.  The file you linked to is identical to the file the author indicated they downloaded. Microsoft Defender Smartscreen is reputation based.  Norton is trash so cares how they determine if a file is legitimate.

Comment: @Ramhound: What - have you managed to download from the user's link? I got a 404 error.

Comment: I absolutely was able to download [this](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-desktop/releases/latest/download/JupyterLab-Setup-Windows.exe) which is identical to [this](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-desktop/releases/tag/v4.0.11-1) once you select `JupyterLab-Setup-Windows.exe` on the page. It's the same GitHub repository. It's not malware.

Comment: @Ramhound: (1) I was able to binary compare the two files and they are identical, so probably this was some internet glitch on my side. There is still one weird fact with his link that the folder itself gives a 404 : https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-desktop/releases/download/v4.0.11-1, so this seems like his URL is being redirected. (2) The installation also comes out as clean on Virus Total, so Norton is indeed showing a false positive. (3) Defender is nowadays a pretty robust antivirus and does a pretty good analysis of executable files, in my experience. I modify my answer.